# VBA - Merging of Excel Workbooks - Possibly running out of Memory

Tags: vba, excel, memory, merge

I've done some google searching and looked around stackoverflow but haven't come across something which resolves the below.

Basically I have around 46 workbooks and worksheets which I need to merge into one for analysis purposes by another software.

```
wbBank.Sheets(c).Copy Before:=wbStructure.Worksheets(wbStructure.Sheets.Count)
```

For some of these worksheets in 'wbStructure', I need to do a copy functionality (per ISO currency or country) which means that from 46 respective worksheets, I end up with around 1300 worksheets for this particular workbook that is ending up consuming too much memory.

For each worksheet I also do the following:

- Insert Rows / Columns depending on parameters set
- go through each row and columns and put in descriptions

The functionality of all of this used to work correctly, however I had to change the functionality recently to keep the same excel object rather than opening a new Excel instance due to compatibility issues between Excel 2016 and Excel 2010.

```
Dim oXLApp As Object
Set oXLApp = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
```

The reason I need to use is that I need to get data from the current Excel document which contains the macro and copy paste this data through the other application. when I tried placing data in another object and then pasting the data, the formatting is lost and creates an issue.

Are there any pointers one can give me to reduce the memory consumption which is resulting in unusual behavior; randomly crashes throughout, issues of "'Not enough system resources to display correctly" etc. The final workbook is substantially large but it has to remain so due to this being an input for another system

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Show more code. In general, what do you mean under "Compatibility issues between Excel 2016 and Excel 2010"? Microsoft usually claims everwhere that their top Office software is perfectly backward compatibile.

Comment: With regard to `R` unfortunately the entire application was written in VBA before R was so popular so rewriting at this point is not possible. 

the issue is that in Excel 2016, copy and pasting between different Excel instances is fully permissible. In Excel 2010, copy / pasting between different Excel instances is a no go. Therefore I had to use the same excel instance `getObject` rather than `createObject`. I suspect that this change is causing the major toll but i'm wondering if there are any other modifications to avoid memory issues

What other areas of code would you like to see?

Comment: Would it be possible to use a hybrid of the Excel 2010 and Excel 2016 code? Like using `if CDbl(Application.Version) > 14 then` (the string `14.0` corresponds to Excel 2010, which was the last version to use MDI - multiple document interface). You could then conditionally execute the branch that is most optimally used for the given software scenario. This approach likely won't help, if your code doesn't run on Excel 2010 at all...

Comment: unfortunately its just crashing due to lack of resources on Office 2010 and I haven't identified an approach to reduce memory usage yet.

Comment: I think in some cases we just have to accept the limitations Excel imposes upon us. When a colleague had a similar problem, he had to slice the input data into several files and trim the data sets to what he really needed, before he could then import and work on it with Excel. Some ideas: Is it possible to switch to 64bit Excel? Is it possible to get rid of Excel 2010? .xlsx files are memory hogs for what data they actually contain. Any file type omitting all the cell formatting information would likely be much better suited.

Comment: And one more general thought: Depending on what data you're working on, that task seems like it would be more appropriately handled by a database (maybe?).

Comment: sounds like you need a database,  you can begin your SQL journey by using a worksheet as a database and use database libraries and logic like ADO.  To query a worksheet using ADO see this blog post http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/02/using-2007-office-system-driver-to.html

Comment: Without looking at your code it's hard to comment on how you can improve the code or suggestions to reduce memory use. Apart from @SMeaden suggestion (which does require different driver based on which version of excel you are using), not sure why you are creating excel object in VBA? Just use references (lot more memory friendly). Plus you shouldn't have to `GetObject` when you are already in the file you need to work with. Second, even though you don't have to clear objects in VBA (garbage collection does clear your objects) but in your case I would suggest clearing your objects